# How to apply a body {} style to specific vue component

Tags: vue.js

I'm using scoped style for most of my components to not interfere with other components.
Some of my views/components need `body { overflow: hidden; }`, but others don't.
I can't use

```html
<style scoped>
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
...
</style>
```

How can i apply this style when specific components are loaded? (i am using vue router if that helps)

Comment: Scoped styles cannot be global: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles. You should probably just use a `<style>` tag for global style, but this doesn't fix the issue where you have multiple Vue components with conflicting `body` styles being loaded on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may send a prop to your component like described in here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Let's call you prop isOverflowHidden, and create .hidden class in your css.

After that, you can add your wrapper element (first tag in component) `:class="{ hidden: isOverflowHidden }"`

Or you can move it to a method.

If you want you can use this this action for inline-styling.

```
<div :style="{ overflow: (isOverflowHidden ? 'hidden' : '')}"></div>
```

You can read extended information in here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles